# Support for undo and redo operations

Tags: nattable

Does NatTable framework for Eclipse IDE bring its own support for *undo* and *redo* operations or provide API for that?

I tried to make a small editor with NatTable but *undo* and *redo* items from the *edit* menu are disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no such support by default. The new DataChangeLayer supports at least something similar that could be adapted. But in general NatTable is a viewer to a list based data model. Tracking changes and supporting undo/redo is currently not part of it.